# how to read last line in a text file using java

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I am making a log and I want to read the last line of the log.txt file, but I'm having trouble getting the BufferedReader to stop once the last line is read.

Here's my code:

```
try {
    String sCurrentLine;

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null)br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686231/java-quickly-read-the-last-line-of-a-text-file

Comment: IMO, this is NOT a duplicate question.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11665098/548225

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a good [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686231/java-quickly-read-the-last-line-of-a-text-file).
  In your code, you could just create an auxiliary variable called `lastLine` and constantly reinitialize it to the current line like so:

```
    String lastLine = "";

    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        lastLine = sCurrentLine;
    }
```

Comment: Your link is recursive? o.O

Comment: That's hilarious. Fixed.

Answer (score 11):

This snippet should work for you:

```
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String last, line;

    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) { 
        last = line;
    }
    //do something with last!
```

Comment: we are checking the not null condition in while loop it self why do we need  the if condition nested inside ?

Comment: @Subayan Mistake on my part, fixed!