# Printing out most recent, rather than first input using for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement

Basically my program lists data into a output file, and then I must then be able to read that output file as an input too in order to list the five most recent data. 
Here is my code:

```
case 2: options = "";
    System.out.println("You have chosen to 'List recent data'" 
                        + "The five most recent data is: " + "\n");

    String data1;
    Scanner inFile2 = new Scanner (new FileReader ("Bankbalance.txt"));

    for (int b=0; b<5; b++) {
        data1 = inFile2.nextLine();
    System.out.println(data1);
    }

        break;
```

Basically the output is giving the first five pieces of data, (I do realise this is because i'm asking it to count the first five) But im just wondering if its possible to display the most recent data instead?? (The data from the bottom of the text file rather than the top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11665098/41576) with some adjustments, try to:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner (new InputStreamReader (new ReverseLineInputStream(file)));

for (int b=0; b<5; b++) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    if (line == null) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: see the answer I referred to, ReverseLineInputStream is written there, you'll have to create and copy it's code to your project

Comment: Ah yeah my bad, forgot to add in the file, its now saying "ReverseLineInputStream cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: should be as simple as creating a new class and copying the code there

Answer (score 0):

Use `RandomAccessFile` class. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html