# Does RandomAccessFile.read() from local file guarantee that exact number of bytes will be read?

Tags: java, buffer, randomaccessfile

Currently my code works fine but should I replace `raf.read()` to `raf.readFully()` in order to ensure that all bytes will be read?

```
            raf = new RandomAccessFile(doc.getFilePath()+"/"+doc.getName(),"r");
            raf.seek((partNumber-1)*partitionSize);
            byte[] buf = new byte[partitionSize];
            int bytesRead = raf.read(buf); //ensure myself by readFully or not?
            System.out.println("expected="+partitionSize+" readed="+bytesRead);
```

My suggestion is the following - when reading from local resource like file one `read()` call anyway will return specified number of bytes. `readFully` useful when reading from network stream, when `read()` does not guarantee that needed bytes count will be read. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read` method does not guarantee to read all requested bytes (even if they exist in the file). The actual behavior is going to be dependent on the underlying OS and file system. For example, when backed by NFS, you may be more likely to not get all the requested bytes in a single call.

If you want to guarantee to get all the requested bytes in a single call, you must use `readFully`.

Answer (score 0):

As it is in documentation for
[RandomAccessFile#read(byte[] b)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29)

> Returns:
>       the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of this file has been reached.

Comment: But does it guarantee, that exactly byte[].length bytes will be read? I quess not, but my test was OK.

Comment: "Returns: the total number of bytes read into the buffer" Means bytes actually read from file. It means less than buffer.lengths and more than 0 , otherwise -1