# Java read .log file from end to start

Tags: java

I am trying to read `.log` file with over 2000 lines from the end to the start.
I can't use [How to read file from end to start (in reverse order) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664705/how-to-read-file-from-end-to-start-in-reverse-order-in-java) , the file is to large.
Here is my code:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
try{
  br = new BufferedReader(new  FileReader(dataFile.getAbsolutePath())); // the log file
}catch(FileNotFoundException FNFE){
  FNFE.printStackTrace();
}
```

And reading the file:

```
String line = null;
String lastLine = null;
while((line=br.readLine()) != null){
  lastLine = line; //setting lastLine to the last line in the file
}
```

Is there a butter way to get this line?

Comment: Do you need only the last line, or all the lines?

Comment: For now only the last line that contians a spesific string.

Comment: Well, the question you linked has a comment with 3 different solutions. Check them out. It's the last comment by hippieshake, if you're not able to use one of them, then there's really no way for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ReversedLinesFileReader](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html) from [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).